# Yii2 - automatically generate placeholder attribute

Tags: php, html, input, yii2, active-form

I'm trying to create an 'auto-placeholder' element using Yii2 and since I couldn't find an actual answer to my question, I thought I'd try it here.

**For example, I have this field:**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', 
    [
        'template'=>'{input}{label}{error}'
    ])
    ->textInput(['placeHolder'=>'{name}')
    ->label(false);
?>
```

However this case would obviously render "name" in the placeholder attribute.
But I would like to generate the placeholder attribute automatically depending on the `model`'s variable I'm using, causing it to render the following:

```
<input type="text" id="loginform-username" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[username]" placeholder="Username">
```

Is there a known way of accessing and inserting the `form->field`'s attribute and displaying it inside its own element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can do by defining the attributes labels in model file like below.

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
      'username' => 'Username',
    ];
}
```

then you can fetch the label automatically based on fields like following.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', 
    [
        'template'=>'{input}{label}{error}'
    ])
    ->textInput(['placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('username'))
    ->label(false);
?>
```

I hope this will sort it out your problem.

Comment: I was actually hoping for a way to fill in the placeholder with a self declaring attribute like {attribute}, but I guess there's no other way than to fill them in manually still.

Comment: @BRO_THOM yes. like template, there is no option to customize as far I know.

Comment: Such a shame. It would safe me a lot of time, being a frontend developer filling in placeholders as just plain annoying. But it is what it is. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in for some extra hassle you can extend ActiveField class for that.

```
class MyActiveField extends \yii\widgets\ActiveField
{
    public function textInput($options = [])
    {
        if (empty($options['placeholder'])) {
            $options['placeholder'] = $this->model->getAttributeLabel($this->attribute);
        }
        return parent::textInput($options);
    }
}
```

Now just need to use your class instead of default one.
You can do every time in view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldClass' => 'fully\qualified\name\of\MyActiveField'
]); ?>
```

Or extend ActiveForm:

```
class MyActiveForm extends \yii\widgets\ActiveForm
{
    $fieldClass = 'fully\qualified\name\of\MyActiveField';
}
```

and use it instead of default ActiveForm widget:

```
<?php $form = MyActiveForm::begin(); ?>
```

Now you can use `<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->textInput() ?>` (or just `<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute') ?>` since `textInput` is default) and placeholder should be there.